# How do I create array of classes in LESS with @loop

Tags: loops, less

How in LESS do I create following array of classes with @loop or some other method

```
.margin-top--1{
    margin-top:-1rem;
}
.margin-top--0-5{
    margin-top:-0.5rem;
}
.margin-top-0{
    margin-top:0rem;
}
.margin-top-0-5{
    margin-top:0.5rem;
}
.margin-top-1{
    margin-top:1rem;
}
```

Comment: Hi wermus, i edited your question to include the code you sent me (or you can edit it yourself, because i'm not sure my edit will be approved :). I added answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about LESS, so there might be a cleaner solution, but this should at least work.

Using loop, like you tried, but replacing a dot in value with a dash, so selector is correct.

To escape value:

1. turn index value into a string, using format function (http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions--format),
2. replace dot with dash, using replace function (http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-replace),
3. assign value after passing it through escape function (http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) to strip quotes.

```html
<style type="text/less">
div {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

@loop-margin-top: 1;
.loop-margin-top (@i) when (@i >= -1) {
   @escapedValue: e(replace(%("%s", @i), "\.", "-", "g"));
   .margin-top-@{escapedValue} {
       margin-top: ~"@{i}rem";
   }
   .loop-margin-top(@i - 0.5);
}
.loop-margin-top (@loop-margin-top);
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.12.2/less.min.js"></script>

<div class="margin-top-1">
1
</div>

<div class="margin-top-0-5">
0.5
</div>

<div class="margin-top-0">
0
</div>

<div class="margin-top--0-5">
-0.5
</div>

<div class="margin-top--1">
-1
</div>
```